# Why this algorithm can sort data in descending order

Tags: python, sorting

I study python programming and try to sort data in descending order.
 #sort1 below is successfully sorted but I cannot understand why this happen. 
Also, `data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[I]` is suspicious point.

```
data = [-1.48,  4.96,  7.84, -4.27,  0.83,  0.31, -0.18,  3.57,  1.48,  5.34,
         9.12,  7.98, -0.75,  2.22, -1.16,  6.53, -5.38,  1.63, -2.85,  7.89,
        -5.96, -8.23,  8.76, -2.97,  4.57,  5.21,  9.43,  3.12,  6.52,  1.58 ]
#sort1

for i in range(30):
    mn = data[i]
    for j in data:
        if j < mn:
            mn = j
            data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i]
        else:
            pass
print('ascending order1:')
print(data)
```

Comment: this is insertion sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: I doubt that `data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[I]` swap adjacent elements. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355075/why-does-looking-up-an-index-before-a-swap-rather-than-inline-change-the-resul/58355342#58355342)

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is insertion sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

You can imagine it as if sorting a streamed list of items:

```
for i in range(30): # for each item streamed here
    mn = data[i]    # take the new item (if exists new item)
    for j in data:  # find its place in the sorted data, and insert it there:
        if j < mn:  # if found its place, insert it here
            mn = j  
            data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i]
```

**UPDATE**

The intuition behind the insertion sort is that you update the previously sorted list each time you get to a new item. So, you don't need to worry about the sorting position of future items.

Since the data before time `i` is sorted, then after the finding the first swap all items will swap until it reaches the time `i` again.

Now, the problem with the swapping command:

```
data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i]
```

This swapping command, in fact, ignores future swappings (when `data.index(mn)` is larger than the current time `i`). However, since it works when time `i` is larger than `data.index(mn)`, that is enough for insertion sort. This is an example of:

```
# two attempts to swapping x and y: 
data = ['x', 'y']

# ignored (target of swap is at time i, found position in future!):
i = 0; mn = 'y' # data.index(mn) == 1
data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i] 
print('ignored swap', data) 

# success (target of swap is at time i, found position in past (before i)):
i = 1; mn = 'x' # data.index(mn) == 0
data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i] 
print('success swap', data)
```

Comment: When uncomment `data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)]`, the sorting fails. It means that `data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)]`fails to swap but help work for sorting?

Comment: when `i` is larger than `data.index(mn)` the swapping works otherwise it is ignored, and that is enough for insertion sort.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in your code:

1. It is better in the loop to do `for i in range(len(data))`, so if the size of the variable **data change**, your code will work.
2. Your code sort data in **descending order**, so you should print: `print('descending order1:')`

Now, let's talk the algorithm part. In fact, your code is the implementation of the sorting algorithm **bubble sort** also knows as **sinking sort**. This algorithm steps through a list repeatedly and compares adjacent elements. It swaps the adjacent elements if they are in the wrong order (i.e if the first element is **inferior** to the second). It does that untill the list is sorted (in the descending order). You can get more understanding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

The code `data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i]` is just the **swap** part. It is a Pythonic way to swap elements. For instance:

```
a = 5
b = 15
a, b = b, a # swap 'elegantly a and b
print(a) #  display 15
print(b) # display 5
```

Comments on the code:

```
for i in range(30): # first cursor: steps through the indexes of the list
    mn = data[i]    # assigns the data at index i to the variable mn
    for j in data:  # second cursor: steps through the data of the list
        if j < mn:  # compares adjacent elements
            mn = j  
            data[i], data[data.index(mn)] = data[data.index(mn)], data[i] # swap adjacent elements
        else: # if the first data superior to the second, don't do anything
            pass
```