# Why does looking up an index *before* a swap rather than inline change the result?

Tags: python, sorting

Consider the following code:

```
data1 = [1.48,  -4.96]
data2 = [1.48,  -4.96]

# i is index we want to swap; mn is the data we want to swap the content of index-i with
i = 0; mn = data[1]

# attempt 1: prior lookup
k = data1.index(mn)
data1[i], data1[k] = data1[k], data1[i]

# attempt 2: in-line lookup
data2[i], data2[data2.index(mn)] = data2[data2.index(mn)], data2[i]

print("Prior lookup:  %r" % data1)
print("Inline lookup: %r" % data2)
```

The output is:

```
Prior lookup:  [-4.96, 1.48]
Inline lookup: [1.48, -4.96]
```

Why aren't these identical?

Comment: Repeated elements?

Comment: It's not the same algorithm. You are calling `data.index(mn)` twice, before and *after* `data` itself has been modified by the assignment to `data[i]`.

Comment: BTW, in an ideal [mcve] you'd only be including the shortest possible `data` array that reproduces the problem *immediately before and after the swap*, and asking why the results differ between the two algorithms; with a reproducer shortened that way you don't need a loop at all, and don't need to be asking about a sort algorithm as a whole, but only about the swap algorithm -- the one specific piece of that sort algorithm that fails.

Comment: I've tried to edit this into a proper MRE, as described above; in this form, the question is simplified to be more readily answerable.

Comment: Thank you for editing, the question become to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add some tracing so we can see order-of-operations:

```
import sys

def findIdx(ary, tgt):
    retval = ary.index(tgt)
    print('First instance of %r in %r is at position %r' % (tgt, ary, retval), file=sys.stderr)
    return retval

data1 = [1.48,  -4.96]
i = 0
mn = data1[1]

k = findIdx(data1, mn)
data1[i], data1[k] = data1[k], data1[i]
print("Prior lookup:  %r" % data1)

data2 = [1.48,  -4.96]
data2[i], data2[findIdx(data2, mn)] = data2[findIdx(data2, mn)], data2[i]
print("Inline lookup: %r" % data2)
```

The logs are then elucidating:

```
First instance of -4.96 in [1.48, -4.96] is at position 1
Prior lookup:  [-4.96, 1.48]
First instance of -4.96 in [1.48, -4.96] is at position 1
First instance of -4.96 in [-4.96, -4.96] is at position 0
Inline lookup: [1.48, -4.96]
```

As you can see, the last call to lookup the index is doing so against an array *that has already had one of its two elements replaced*.

Comment: Thank you, I've got it. to see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354376/10595988). 
> This swapping command, in fact, ignores future swappings (when data.index(mn) is larger than the current time i). However, since it works when time i is larger than data.index(mn), that is enough for insertion sort.